# How to differentiate between identical printer drivers in settings list?

Tags: 18.04, printing, hp

While trying to setup HP LaserJet Pro M501 (m501dn) in KDE I'm getting a list of multiple (8) identical drivers in the driver selection dialog, named "LaserJet Pro M501 Postscript (recommended) (en)":

[image: drivers list]

Is there a way to check if they differ in anything or if this is just the same driver printed multiple times somehow? I cannot use printing on both sides after upgrade to 18.04

```
$ lpstat -t M501
scheduler is running
no system default destination
device for HP_LaserJet_Pro_M501dn: socket://###.###.###.###:9100
device for Unknown: socket://###.###.###.###:9100
HP_LaserJet_Pro_M501dn accepting requests since ср, 07-лис-2018 21:10:12 +0200
Unknown accepting requests since ср, 07-лис-2018 21:00:18 +0200
printer HP_LaserJet_Pro_M501dn is idle.  enabled since ср, 07-лис-2018 21:10:12 +0200
printer Unknown is idle.  enabled since ср, 07-лис-2018 21:00:18 +0200
```

Comment: what is this an image of? Please post TEXT and not images since we can use text  . Next: please do a `lpstat -t M501`  and add the results. You can also use `cups`  from http:/localhost:631`  and see what is registered there.

Comment: This a screenshot of a driver selection dialog. Added text from the screenshot and `lpstat` output

Comment: well that looks like it is the same line (you only have one printer listed). The Unknown is odd though and might also be related. See if you can remove that one :)  Oh and something else: have a look inside /etc/cups/printers.conf Maybe that has entries you can delete

Comment: Unknown is just another printer that works fine, printed the document I needed there. I found that there are just two actual files in `/usr/share/ppd/HP`: 
`hp-laserjet_pro_m501dn-ps.ppd.gz` and `hp-laserjet_pro_m501n-ps.ppd.gz`. Thank you for trying to help, this question can be considered solved. Still leaves two bugs to report :multiple entries for one driver and inability to use double-sided printing.

Comment: The unpacked version in `/etc/cups/ppd/HP_LaserJet_Pro_M501dn.ppd` is  an uncompressed copy of the `dn` version so I've selected the correct driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are just two actual files in `/usr/share/ppd/HP`

```
hp-laserjet_pro_m501dn-ps.ppd.gz
hp-laserjet_pro_m501n-ps.ppd.gz
```

So this is a [bug of the driver selection dialog](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=400844).